# Using SlowCheetah without NuGet

Tags: nuget, slowcheetah

I've just started using SlowCheetah. When I right click my config file and choose "Add Transform" it doesn't only add the extra config files for all my configuration, but it also install a NuGet package which in turn adds a bunch of files to my solution.

**Is the NuGet package required?** I'd really prefer NOT to use NuGet at all in this project.

If it is not required, **is there an easy way to add the transforms without installing the NuGet package?**

I will always build the solution in Visual Studio (not on a build server) and it's ok to require that SlowCheetah is installed on the computer that is used for the build.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Edit:
I've tried just uninstalling the NuGet package, but then the transformation doesn't work... :(

Comment: The NuGet package is now required. You can edit the project/packages.config to get around it but thats not recommended.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi, you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet package is now required. You can edit the project/packages.config to get around it but that's not recommended.